# Add Excel formula containing a file path that may not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a formula to a range of cells which performs a `VLOOKUP` against a file which at that point in time may not exist. I cannot find a way to do this without it prompting me to select the file when it doesn't. When I hit escape it just defaults to a `#N/A` error, which is precisely the functionality that I want, only without having to hit the Escape button repeatedly.

As an example, my formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,'R:\Folder Path\[File_that_wont_exist_until_later.xlsx]Data'!$A:$D,4,FALSE)
```

So is there a way of preventing the dialog being displayed? I've tried setting `DisplayAlerts` to false but the dialog still appears.

Comment: Are you sure, when I applied Application.DisplayAlerts = False before the formula,the prompt box doesn't appear, it just inputs #N/A on the sheet.

Comment: Yes you're right, I set `DisplayAlerts` to false in the immediate window which didn't prevent the dialog, but when I put it in the actual code it did. Thanks for making me double-check!

Comment: Hehe....Cheers, I am adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
=VLOOKUP(B1,'R:\Folder Path\[File_that_wont_exist_until_later.xlsx]Data'!$A:$D,4,FALSE)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Adding this will remove the prompt box displayed.